# save data in obtainPermanentIDsForObjects (NSIncrementalStore)

Tags: core-data

NSIncrementalStore has a required method "obtainPermanentIDsForObjects".

To get the ID's I have to create new row's in the database. Then to save the data in 
executeRequest:withContext:error:, I have to hit the DB again.

Is there a reason why I shouldn't get new rowID's and save the data at the same time in obtainPermanentIDsForObjects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is probably not, if your entities have relationships.

To save a relationship, you need to uniquely identify the corresponding objects. Identifying an object requires your internal identifier which can be obtain via the permanent objectID (NSManagedObjectID).

But (some of) your objects won't have a permanent and internal ID yet because they haven't been handled yet in "obtainPermanentIDsForObjects"

In other words first you need to assign permanentID's (and thus also internalID's) before you can save references to them.